# Возможно ли отключить зарядку по USB от компьютера?

Tags: android, администрирование, железо, usb

Если подключаю какое-нибудь Android устройство по USB, то оно автоматически начинает заряжаться. Можно ли это отключить? В биосе не нашёл подобной опции, у девайса в настройках тоже.

Я хочу делать зарядку при почти полной разрядке батареи от специального зарядника, как указано в инструкции к устройству, а не по чуть-чуть заряжать всякий раз, когда подключаю его к компу.